# Make .delay() and .animate() function re-run everytime a classes div opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but after 2 days of research I cannot find a solution.

**The Story:**
I have a dynamic page.  When you get to one section and click on one of the 6 options it pulls up some info (name, place, etc.).  I have a jQuery function that makes that info hide about half way after a few seconds.  When you hover over that section with the mouse it also will animate up and back down as the mouse leaves it.

**The Problem:**
How do I make the whole function run again if another of those 6 option is clicked? Each time an option is selected the class with that info comes up, but after this function runs once (the delay part and animate down part) it just stays minimized unless you hover over it.  I want it to appear every time and then run through the function.  I have tried a number of things, and I'm sure there is a simple solution, just not sure what it is.

Here is a link to my codepen with a sample: http://codepen.io/jsegarra/pen/GxByr

I have also tried to wrap that all in a click function, for clicking on one of those 6 options and thought that would do the trick, but still the same thing:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.title').click(function () {
    $('.bottomTab').delay(5000).animate({
        height: '50px' // to 50px
    }, 'slow');

    $(".bottomTab").hover(
      //on mouseover
      function () {
          $(this).stop().animate({
              height: '+=100'  //adds 50px
          }, 'slow');
      },
      //on mouseout
      function () {
          $(this).stop().animate({
              height: '50px' //back to 50px
          }, 'slow');
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset the div css before re-running the function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.title').click(function () {
   $('.bottomTab').css('height', '100px').delay(500).animate({
    height: '50px' // to 50px
}, 'slow');

$(".bottomTab").hover(
  //on mouseover
  function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({
          height: '+=100'  //adds 50px
      }, 'slow');
  },
  //on mouseout
  function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({
          height: '50px' //back to 50px
      }, 'slow');
  });
});
});
```

Here is the html I used with that javascript

```
<div class="title">title</div>
<div class="bottomTab">This is going to move from just being about 50 pixels high to about 100 pixels high after i add in some mouseenter and mouse out events</div>
```

I used the same CSS of your code pen, and the result was a full reclickable option

Comment: I was actually onto something similar but it wasn't working right for me.  I will try this and let you know if it works! Thanks!

Comment: YES!!! This did exactly what I was looking for.  I had that idea, i just had put the .css as another function after the .delay so it wasn't quite working right and I had dismissed it as an answer.  This does exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you know a simple way to add a line for a max height?  If someone where to mouse back and forth real quick it keeps going higher (the div).  I put in the .stop() to not make it jerky and continue to go up and down if someone moused in and out rapidly, but it does seem to keep growing taller if you do that.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I'm glad this helped :). For the max height: just add this to your tab css   `max-height: 100px;`

Comment: Wow, I knew that was a stupid question, I literally just had a duh moment there and tried that and was coming back here to say nm! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. Your code seems to works fine. You've just typed an error while transfering to CodePen. Replace `$('this').hover(` with `$('.bottomTab').hover(`.

Comment: Yes it works, but when I click anywhere else on the page (go to a completely different section) and come back to that div it just stays minimized.  I need it to start the whole function (delay etc.) over everytime i click into that section.  I'll correct the codepen, thank!

Comment: @Stan One can only guess what else on your page is happening. You don't point that out in your code. You should show in CodePen what's actually going wrong. There must be a problem in the code you haven't shown yet. When clicking around, nothing breaks the maximize/minimize functionality in this example.

Comment: Yes there is a bunch of other stuff going on, so i tried to just show this part of it.  Its a dynamic page so everything is in one html file, and when someone navigates to the projects sections of the site there are 10 groups of 6 projects, so those 6 projects come up in a menu, and when someone clicks a project that menu disappears and this div shows up, then after a few seconds is minimizes and can pop back up on hover.  That works fine the first time you click a project, if you go back and click a different project, that effect doesn't start over, the div is just staying minimized.